# Packing problem : items into constrained bins (Solution to singular matrix)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, matrix, packing

EDIT: the way I have attempted to solve this with simultaneous equations may not actually work, any other approaches would be appreciated.

I have a set of containers, each with a maximum capacity n, and a set of item types that they can contain.

I then have a combination of items and I want to know if my containers can hold all of the items.

EG:

```
Bin 0, capacity 2, item types stored (b,d)
Bin 1, capacity 3, item types stored (b,c)
Bin 2, capacity 2, item types stored (c,d)
```

Attempt to store 3d, 2c, 2b -  success : Bin 0-dd, Bin 1-cbb, Bin 2-dc.

I need as an output a solution if one / many exists, or null if there is no solution.

NOTE: there is no constraint on the number of item types a bin can hold, or the total number of items.

I have tried constructing linear simultaneous equations and using JAMA to solve them, however the matrix is non singular which I think means infinite solutions / no solutions. If there are infinite solutions then I just need one of them.

```
    EG I get these equations
    d0 + d2 = 3
    b0 + b1 = 2
    c1 + c2 = 2
    b0 + d0 = 2
    b1 + c1 = 3
    c2 + d2 = 2
    with these variables
    [d0, d2, c1, c2, b0, b1] where d0 is the number of d in bin 0

    Leading to these arrays LHS
    [1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
    [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], 
    [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0],
    [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0]]

   RHS
   [3.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 2.0]
```

```
    Matrix lhs = new Matrix(lhsArray);
    Matrix rhs = new Matrix(rhsArray, rhsArray.length);
    Matrix ans = lhs.solve(rhs);
```

I get an error saying the array is singular. This doesnt mean it's unsolvable does it? As the solution d0 = 2, c1 =1, b1 = 2, d2 = 1, c2 = 1 solves it.

Comment: This almost sounds like Linear Programming, but not quite. If you aren't familiar with this technique, you should at least look at the basics in case you need it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest sorting your items by type such that you end up with a list of types and counts for that type in diminishing order.

Then count the capacity of your containers for the type you have the most items of. If you have enough capacity, add the items and update the containers, and repeat with the next type. If at any point your remaining containers do not have enough capacity for the next type of items in your list, get a list of currently full containers which can contain the current type, and attempt to re-allocate items they currently contain to containers which cannot contain the current type. If the number of full containers + empty containers is not enough to hold all of the current type, or it is impossible to reallocate enough items from currently full containers, your problem has no solution.

Note that there might be more efficient ways to plan container allocation, but this general approach should work, and will return only a single solution(which you want), even if multiple solutions exist.

Edit: In your example, the algorithm would sort your items into 3d, 2b, 2c. It would then check the capacity of d, which will be 4(2 from bin 0, 2 from bin 2). Then it places your 3 d type items, 2 in 0, 1 in 2. Next it considers 2b. Remaining capacity is 3(from bin 1), so it deposits both items into bin 1. Finally it considers 2c. Total capacity is 2(1 remaining in bin 1, and 1 remaining in bin 2). It places those items accordingly, and now your list is empty, so it returns a single solution (Bin 0: 2d; Bin 1: 2b, 1c; Bin 2: 1d, 1c).

Another example, showing a redistribution:

Bin 0, capacity 2(b, d)
Bin 1, capacity 3(c, d)
Bin 2, capacity 2(b, c)

Items: 4d, 3b

Initially allocate 2 d to bin 0 and the other 2 to bin 1.

Now we have a problem - we have 3b and only 2 open capacity(in bin 2).

The algorithm then finds full containers which can hold b, which is only bin 0, and attempts to reallocate 1 of the d type items there. It can do this because bin 1 still has 1 open capacity and can hold type d(but not b), and now we have available capacity in bin 0 for the remaining b type item.

Note that you can certainly still implement containers as matrices(or probably any number of other ways), but this solution does not rely on solving them as a system of linear equations.